# How to save a DataTable to SQLite DB?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable, dataadapter

I'm trying to perform a simple task, however, all the examples I'm finding do not work.
I have a very simple case: 
I have a dataTable that belongs to a dataSet. It is populated from some text file that I parsed (not CSV).
I just want to save that dataTable into SQLite DB, where I have an empty table with the same schema (same number of columns and format of columns).
I have this method:

```
        public static void UpdateTable(string dbpath, DataSet dataSet, string tableName)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection($"URI=file:{dbpath}"))
        {
            db.Open();
            dataSet.AcceptChanges();

            SQLiteDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from " + tableName, db);



            DataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
            SQLiteCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(DataAdapter);
            DataAdapter.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            DataAdapter.Update(dataSet, tableName);

        }

    }
```

This is the last way I tried. All I'm getting is the same empty table in SQLite DB.
All I want to do is just save a table into a DB. I guess I can do that row by row, but I know there is a way to do that in one command.
Could you please help me write a functioning method?

Comment: do you receive any error with connection string or table name?

Comment: It's been a while with dataset for me, but I think you need to mark the data as "modified". Otherwise update will be a nop. If I remember correctly.

Comment: No errors, just an empty table as a result. I'll try to mark the data as modified, thanks!